# Как правильно установить файл metainfo.xml для собранного пакета flatpak?

Tags: linux, xml, сборка, fedora, flatpak

Начал следовать инструкции в [документации](https://docs.flatpak.org/ru/latest/first-build.html) `flatpak` по созданию собственного пакета:

1. Создал тестовый файл `hello.sh`, в котором просто было echo "text"
2. Создал манифест `org.flatpak.Hello.yml`:

```
app-id: org.flatpak.Hello
runtime: org.freedesktop.Platform
runtime-version: '22.08'
sdk: org.freedesktop.Sdk
command: hello.sh
modules:
  - name: hello
    buildsystem: simple
    build-commands:
      - install -D hello.sh /app/bin/hello.sh
    sources:
      - type: file
        path: hello.sh
```

3. Собрал приложение:

```
$ flatpak-builder build-dir org.flatpak.Hello.yml
```

4. Протестировал сборку (успешно):

```
$ flatpak-builder --user --install --force-clean build-dir org.flatpak.Hello.yml
$ flatpak run org.flatpak.Hello
```

После команды `run` увидел вывод скрипта `hello.sh`

5. Поместил приложение в репозиторий:

```
$ flatpak-builder --repo=repo --force-clean build-dir org.flatpak.Hello.yml
```

6. Успешно установил его из репозитория:

```
$ flatpak --user remote-add --no-gpg-verify tutorial-repo repo
$ flatpak --user install tutorial-repo org.flatpak.Hello
```

7. Успешно запустил установленное приложение:

```
$ flatpak run org.flatpak.Hello
```

---

У меня появилось несколько вопросов по итогу всей этой процедуры:

1. Почему приложение не отображается в магазине приложений (у меня Fedora 37)?
2. Почему после выполнения команды `flatpak build-update-repo repo` я получаю такой вывод:

```
Нет appstream данных для app/org.flatpak.Hello/x86_64/master: No such file or directory: /files/share
```

Логично, что из-за того что нет appstream данных, но как их добавить? Потому что я уже пытался это сделать, используя [онлайн генератор](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/appstream/metainfocreator/#/). У меня получился такой `xml` файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<component type="console-application">
  <id>org.flatpak.Hello</id>
  
  <name>Cool Program Hello</name>
  <summary>It&apos;s good solution for ML</summary>
  
  <metadata_license>FSFAP</metadata_license>
  <project_license>0BSD</project_license>
  
  <description>
    <p>
      Details details and details!
    </p>
  </description>
  
  <icon type="stock">coolprogramhello</icon>
  
  <categories>
    <category>Development</category>
    <category>Construction</category>
  </categories>
  
  <provides>
    <binary>hello.sh</binary>
  </provides>
</component>
```

Круто, конечно, что у меня есть файл с метаинформацией, но то, что я не знаю куда его деть, совсем не круто. На сайте, где находится сам генератор я нашел следующее:

> Установите этот файл как /usr/share/metainfo/org.flatpak.cool_program_hello.metainfo.xml

> Вы можете проверить эти метаданные локально, выполнив:appstreamcli validate org.flatpak.cool_program_hello.metainfo.xml

Я, конечно же выполнил эти инструкции. Поместил файл и переименовал, как там описано. Но это не помогло. Скажу больше: я даже сделал это при помощи `appstreamcli put <filename>`. Но боюсь он просто делает тоже самое, что я делаю руками при копировании файла.

---

Я бы очень хотел понять, как и куда этот файл устанавливать, чтобы все работало как надо, спасибо за внимание